# SourceTree connecting to a server ip

Tags: git, using, atlassian-sourcetree

I need help with something(duh).

For work I have to connect to a gitrepostery.
The part of the public key is done, however the only things i got are a server ip, a git repostery and a user name.
However, i can't connect to the repostery, simply stating that the server doesnt exit. 
I have tried filling the IP, the repostery and the user name, I've tried the PROTOCOL stuff, doens't work and i'm desperate.
Can you guys please help me?
The server ip looks like this:

12.34.56.789
(this isn't the real one, just an example ofc)

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the right url, and it depends on which protocol you are using.

via `ssh`

```
git@IP:REPO_NAME.git
```

If you want to use ssh, you need to [set your ssh key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) first.

via `https`

```
https://IP/REPO_NAME.git
```

Comment: I've tried your way, but it didnt work. With the HTTPS I got the error that there was no error and with the ssh I got acces denied, even though the git has no password in it. Any advise you can give me?